# Character escaping in regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, escaping

I used this regex to match a hyperlink that contains a specific word in the href

```
<a( .*?)? href=\".*?" + word + ".*?\"( .*?)?>.*?</a>
```

This returns the first appearance of the matched link

Now i need to find all hyperlinks withthe same match, and I have tried this regex:

```
/<a [^>]*\bhref\s*=\s*"[^"]*word.*?<\/a>/
```

I'm having some problems making my compiler accept this expression. The problem seems to be escaping some special characters. It seems this part is a problem

```
"[^"]
```

I tried escaping the [ with \, and putting @ in front of double quotes, but no luck.

The error reads "bad compile constant value".

Does anyone know how to format this regex to satisfy the compiler?

Comment: you need to escape `"`  with `""`..But why use regex for this.is there any reason for not considering html parsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex is not a good way to parse HTML files..

You should use [htmlagilitypack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://yourWebSite.com");

List<String> hrefLst=doc.DocumentNode
                        .SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
                        .Select(x=>x.Attributes["href"].Value)
                        .Where(y=>y.Contains(word))
                        .ToList();
```

`hrefLst` now has all your required links.

Isn't that simple!

Answer (score 1):

Although you can escape everything that needs to be escaped in the string, regular expressions are far easier to read when the string is @-quoted. The only thing you then need to worry about are double quotes, which need to be doubled.

```
string expression = @"/<a [^>]*\bhref\s*=\s*""[^""]*word.*?<\/a>/";
```

Note: As the comments say, this regex might fail. I haven't tested it, I just modified it to make it compile.

Comment: there are 1000's of cases for this regex to fail!:P..dont use regex..am begging you :(

Comment: @joey Or you could just say "the slashes at the beginning and end are not needed"